# need to use a php block in my globalStyles.css file

Tags: php, css

My globalStyles.css has been stable for 3 weeks and is used everywhere in the project.  After studying several SO posts and responses it seems some people like to put their global CSS stuff into a .php file to avoid the type of problem I'm having.

Here is the issue.

At the top of my project's files I have a PHP block -- here's the top of my index.php:

```
  <?php
   include 'titleBar.php';

   require_once 'navBar.php';

   require_once 'theDatabase.php'; // functions for the UI and DB access

   require_once 'globals.php'; // variables and statics used throughout
  ?>
```

Deeper into each file - such as my index.php above -- is this statement:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $sitePath ?>globalStyles.css" />
```

$sitePath comes from globals.php, looks like this:

```
   $sitePath = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/Artifacks/";
```

('Artifacks' is the project name.  Real nice, I didn't pick it.)

Then I use $sitePath like this all over the place, for example:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $sitePath?>images/Artifacks-icon.png"></img>
```

Does this work?  Oh my goodness.  Incredible -- like fresh Gumbo and biscuits.  And stable for weeks too.

Notice that I said above the **link rel="stylesheet" globalStyles.css**  comes **after** the **require_once 'globals.php'**
inside my index.php file (and all the other files in the project for that matter -- globalStyles.css is pulled in AFTER globals.php, in all files).

By the time the link rel pulls the globalStyles.css into my index.php -- the $sitePath is 'visible' already since it came from globals.php which was included *before* globalStyles.css.

So inside my globalStyles.css I added this:

```
   background-image: url('<?php echo $sitePath; ?>images/egypt-Sphinx.jpg ) ;
```

The image does NOT appear.

So I thought 'okay even though globalStyles.css is pulled into index.php AFTER
the require_once 'globals.php' --  for whatever reason my $sitePath in globals.php is not 'visible' to the code inside globalStyles.css.

To prove that, I hard-coded inside globalStyles.css the full path to egypt-Sphinx.jpg  and this image now appears fine.

So I added this to globalStyles.css:

But my Netbeans IDE tells me "invalid content."

How can I reference $sitePath inside globalStyles.css?

I need this statement to work -- I can't hardcode paths anymore because we're deploying to the staging server then to the production server - I need to make the following work or to have its desired effect implemented SOMEhow:

**Inside my globalStyles.css I need this to somehow work:**

```
  .grayDecorative
   {
      background-image: url('<?php echo $sitePath; ?>images/egypt-Sphinx.jpg ) ;
      /* other styles here.........*/
   }
```

I have tried it without the semicolon after $sitePath and still no image.

When I 'echo' the $sitePath it DOES have a trailing slash:

```
    http://localhost/Artifacks/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run php in your stylesheet, then this should help.

You will have to alter the structure just a bit.  Change globalstyles to a php file, and call it in your link line like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $sitePath ?>globalStyles.php" />` line.

Then, rename the css to globalStyles.php, but add the following to the very top:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/css");
    header("Vary: Accept");
?>
```

You can now add any php that you need to the stylesheet.  For example:

```
background-image: url('<?php echo $sitePath; ?>images/egypt-Sphinx.jpg );
```

will work, because it will get parsed by the php handler before it is returned as a stylesheet.

Comment: cale_b this has solved in a creative way a problem I didn't know I had - unlike a .php file, inside a .css file I can't just start playing around with different script languages -- from now on I'm going to structure my external .css files as you outline here. For nested subfolders where the site assets might be buried, your technique here seems like it will work -- thanks.  Now I have to figure out which of these two to Accept.  Here's a +1 in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this (as you write you do) to link to your stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $sitePath ?>globalStyles.css" />
```

And your background image is located here:

```
background-image: url('<?php echo $sitePath; ?>images/egypt-Sphinx.jpg ) ;
```

You can just write:

```
background-image: url("images/egypt-Sphinx.jpg") ...
```

That's how CSS works. All URLs in that CSS file are relative to the CSS file itself.

```
<sitepath> globalStyles.css
<sitepath> images/egypt-Sphinx.jpg
```

Comment: I have to give you +1 on this one!  That fixed this particular case, although cale_b came up with a general solution that from here on out I will using.  These 2 solutions are like Einstein's Special Relativity and General Relativity - Thanks Hakre!

Comment: Take care with using PHP to serve CSS. This can have more negative implications that you're able to see in the beginning where it seems to be amazing. Stick to static CSS files as long as you can. If you can't you most often have a flaw with your design, so even then it's much better to look twice again.